# python3 tkinter on WSL: app icon not being displayed

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using `tkinter` in Ubuntu (inside Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)). I'm trying to set the icon (`.icon` or `.png`) to my `tkinter` app, but all the methods I tried fail. My solutions are based on [Set Window Icon in Tkinter](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-set-window-icon-in-tkinter/).

Here I put my code and the results in comments:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

#root.iconbitmap('./icon.ico')
#error
#return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
#_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "./icon.ico" not defined

#root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, tk.PhotoImage(file='./logo.png'))
#works, but empty icon

#root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file=r"./logo.png"))
#works, but empty icon

root.mainloop()
```

This is the empty icon:

[image]

All solutions work in Windows.

Comment: ICO file is not supported by `tkinter` in Linux.

Comment: And what about `.png` files? They don't work.

Comment: Yes. You can use a PNG image with `.iconphoto()`.

Comment: `root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='logo.png'))` produces the screenshot I added to the question. The icon shown doesn't correspond to ``logo.png`, I think it's a Linux default icon. On Windows, it works.

Answer (score 0):

try removing './' and leave only 'icon.ico'

Comment: I doesn't work on Windows Subsystem for Linux. If I try on Windows, it doesn't matter if there is a './' or not, it works. `.ico` files aren't supported on Linux according to @acw1668 comment in the question, but the `.png` files produce a default Linux icon (I assume it is).